# wrong multiplication result for __uint128_t result

Tags: c++, 128-bit

I want to multiple two 64 bits numbers and store their results into two 64 bits (total 128) bits variables

for this I wrote following simple function

```
void multiply2(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t& hi, uint64_t& lo) {
__uint128_t product = static_cast<__uint128_t>(a) * static_cast<__uint128_t>(b);
hi = static_cast<uint64_t>(product >> 64);
lo = static_cast<uint64_t>(product);}}
```

and then I test is using following

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

uint64_t a = 4539155444;
uint64_t b = 4539155444;
uint64_t hi, lo;
multiply1(a, b, hi, lo);
std::cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << hi << lo << std::endl;
return 0;}
```

The output I am getting is

```
4539155444 * 4539155444 = 12157188071085285520
```

But expected output is
`4539155444 * 4539155444 = 20603932144794837136`

I am confused what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't just print out two decimal numbers next to each other and get a valid result (it would work in hex), you'll need to convert back to 128bit for printing, your answer is `1` and `2157188071085285520` which are the correct 64-bit numbers

Comment: It does not work like this. You can only print it this way using hexadecimal notation, but not a decimal number

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: The split happens between two binary digits, not between two decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant simply take two parts of the number and print the next to each other and get the correct decimal number. You need to write your own function to print it.

```
void printi128(__int128 val)
{
    if(val < 10 && val > -10) printf("%d", val);
    else 
    {
        printi128(val / 10);
        printf("%d", abs(val % 10));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bTYsEbrsM

Comment: `printf("%d", val)` has undefined behavior. It should be `printf("%d", static_cast<int>(val))`

Comment: No need to use recursion here either, a simple loop would be better

Comment: @0___________ My comments were about defects in code that you originally posted. I see that you fixed the algorithm.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili it is not UB. Read the code

Comment: @ÖöTiib it was the original intention.

Comment: @0___________ You added the cast after my comment? The edit history is public.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili removed the cast

Comment: @0___________ It is undefined without the cast. `%d` specifier is for `int`. It is not for `__int128` regardless of the runtime magnitude of the value you're passing.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili no it is not because of the implicit conversion when you pass to variadic function

Comment: @0___________ Implicit promotion to `int` does not apply to `__int128`. Just like how it doesn't apply to `long long`, otherwise there would be no way to print `long long`. The compiler itself will tell you that if you turn on the warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/favWzcEcb